# Map two fields into one with DRF

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

Say I have model `Team` and it has a one-to-many relation with `Player` and `Standin`

I can serialize them like this:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    players = PlayerSerializer(many=True)
    standins = StandinSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = '__all__'
```

So output will be:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    ...
    "players": [...],
    "standins": [...]
}
```

How could i get:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    ...
    "roster": {
        "players": [...],
        "standins": [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the to_representation method on your sereializer:

```py
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super(TeamSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    ret['roster'] = {
        'players': ret['players'],
        'standins': ret['standins']
        }
    del ret['players']
    del ret['standins']
    return ret
```